# PHP, Break Up String with Ampersand

Tags: php, strpos, ampersand

I have spent a lot of time searching the web for this, so before someone slams me for not looking ... trust me, I have.

The problem: I am working with a string that includes an ampersand, to display two names. The difficulty: at times I may need to pull the name on the left, or the name on the right for display. The additional difficulty is that some of the names may include HTML entities, which of course also use an ampersand.

Example: I may use something as simple as:

"Fred & Wilma"

To get just "Fred" from the string, I tried using the PHP function STRPOS(), but I get nothing.

```
$nPos = strpos( " & ", $names );
```

Note that I am using spaces on either side to avoid issues with HTML entities.

More fun, checking to see if I get no results:

```
if ( $nPos === 0 )
{
   echo "String ' $' not found in " . $names . "<br />";
}
```

Does not return a value. This tells me, from the various documentation and such on the web that I can find, that I should have a value for $nPos that is useful.

If I add:

```
echo "Position of string ' & ': " . $nPos . "<br />";
```

I get a blank value after the text in double quotes.

I am at a loss how to do what I need here. I need to get the position of the " & " characters, but am not getting it. From there obviously use of the substr() function would be necessary to get the values from the left and/or right of the ampersand.

Comment: In addition to the answers correcting your use of `strpos`, please not that `if($nPos === 0)` checks if the needle was found at position `0` in the haystack. You should change it to `if($nPos === FALSE)`.

Comment: You might consider deciding HTML entities so you can deal with the characters they represent.  After all, the correct way to have an ampersand in an HTML is `&amp;`. Re-encode as required afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strpos` first parameter is haystack - string in which you do the search & second is needle - string you searching for. So just swap parameters:
`$nPos = strpos(  $names, " & " );`

You can find more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Gotta love PHP and it's consistancy with needle/haystack parameter ordering.

Comment: It is consistent: string functions are haystack, needle and array functions are needle, haystack.

Comment: Thanks -- it was, as noted, the consistency of PHP and parameter ordering that threw me off completely. The suggestion of using explode() is one I had not considered as I am not that familiar with it (I have only recently learned of it). This resolves the issue at the moment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you just needs the names, I would break it into an array:

```
$nameArray = explode(' & ', $names);
```

This won't split unexpectedly on HTML because `&` is not followed by a space in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `explode($delimeter, $subject_string)` function, which is built-in PHP. For example:

```
$names = 'firstName & lastName';
// use `&` as delimeter to split on and callback `trim` function on each array item
$names_array = array_map('trim',explode(' & ', $names));
```

now $names_array will look like this:

```
array(
  [0] => 'firstName'
  [1] => 'lastName'
)
```

and can be access as as following:

```
$firstName = $names_array[0];
$lastName = $names_array[1];
```

Comment: Strpos is good for seeing whether the substring exists,  but I think this explode is a more elegant way to actually extract them.

Comment: OP said spaceless `'&'` will not do as a delimiter.  See MattS's answer.  I would downvote this answer if I thought it would make a difference.